# Unity - Callback when a package is removed but before recompile

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a Unity package I want to give to other people to help with translations. Currently, I only handle the Text component but I would like to handle TMPro too.

My idea is to create a conditional compilation tag to prevent any TMPro line of code from compiling (and causing errors) when it's not imported. That part is the easy one, I managed to do that. I also managed to add the tag when TMPro gets imported or when it's already in the project as I import my custom package. The thing I cannot manage to do is to remove my tag when TMPro gets removed. Since everything is reloading, the compilation crashes because it cannot find TMPro anymore. Thus my question in the title.

I'm also completely open to any other solution than this one, as long as it doesn't involve assemblies.

More infos : I want my package to work in Unity 2019, 2020 and 2021

Comment: _"My idea is to create a conditional compilation tag to prevent any TMPro line of code from compiling (and causing errors) when it's not imported"_ - huh?  If you prevent it from compiling how then are errors produced?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `AssetPostprocessor` class. With the method on below, it gives you import, delete and move callbacks.

```cs
public class AssetManager : AssetPostprocessor
{
    public static void OnPostprocessAllAssets(string[] importedAssets, string[] deletedAssets, string[] movedAssets,
        string[] movedFromAssetPaths)
    {
        foreach (var deletedAsset in deletedAssets)
        {
            Debug.Log(deletedAsset);
        }
    }
}
```

> The following code must be in the **Editor** Folder.

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for this but every time it was something post compilation! 
I see it's something that is called every time something is done on any asset. It is working but not very optimized. Would you have any idea on how to do something similar only for packages, other than checking with an if statement in the foreach ? (If not, I'll make your answer the solution, obviously)

Comment: @AlexisFERRER What do you mean by no optimization? Optimization is written in code out of update at all, the issue is not so important. All sub-code, even written in Unity Editor, all uses a comprehensive event that controls the output and input of files. The entry and exit of partial content (packages) without exception is determined by the if condition. There is no event as to which package has been deleted and which package has not been deleted, while if possible that event is a subset of the comprehensive event and has the same performance.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, that is what I was wondering.